# Passing value from component to JS

Tags: javascript, angular

How to passing value from component to js file ? Thank you very much.

**app.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Time</td>
    <td>Title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
    <td>
      <a href="#" onClick="openWin()">{{data.createDatetime}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" onClick="openWin(data.title)">{{data.title}}</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**script.js** (in assets folder)

```
function openWin(title) {
    // open popup windows
    // show title
}
```

Comment: You can pass `data` in parameter like  `(click)="openWin(data)"`

Comment: In **script.js** how to use data, example show data.title ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You will get whole object so
`function openWin(data) {
   console.log(data.title);

}`

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use (click) instead of onclick with angular

```
<a href="#" (click)="openWin(data)">
```

And inside ts,

```
openWin(data:any){
   console.log(data.title);
}
```